# Create a Group RW-access for a KVM shared folder via virtiofs on Ubuntu Server 22

Tags: kvm-virtualization, file-sharing, ubuntu-22.04, virtio

I have a folder `/common` on an **Ubuntu Server 22** host which is RW accessible by all users in group `users` i.e. user `alice` (with uid `1000`) is a member of `users` (with gid `12345`) and has fuull RW access to `/common` on the host.

On a KVM (also Ubuntu Server 22) on that host, I have the same user `alice` and group `users` with the same `uid` and `gid` respectively. The subuid and subgid (read from `cat /etc/subuid` and `cat /etc/subgid`) are different on both host and KVM.

I am sharing this folder from the Host to the KVM via **virtiofs** with the mount tag `common-mount`, using this entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
common-mount /common virtiofs defaults 0 0
```

followed by `sudo mount -a` to mount the folder

However the mounted folder `/common` on that KVM is **read-only** to KVM user `alice` despite having the same uid and belonging to `users`. If I `chmod 777` the folder `/common` on the host, that becomes accessible on the KVM, but I need `chmod 775` for group RW-access and security.

*Based on this link https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html the differing subuid and subgid might be behind the issue, but when I made attempts to map them using idmap, the KVM became unbootable. If this relates to the solution, I am uncertain of the correct syntax.*